# wrong in retrive sql query in php pager code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pager

My problem is that I want a page to show 10 records only
and I found this great code at [phpjabbers](http://www.phpjabbers.com/php--mysql-select-data-and-split-on-pages-php25.html):

```
    Host = "localhost"
    user="root"
    password=""(Nothing)

<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Unable to connect");
    $db = mysql_select_db("test",$con) or die("Unable to select DB");

    if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }
    else
    {
        $page = 1;
    }

    $sf = ($page-1) * 10;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students LIMIT ".$sf.",10";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    //echo $rs;
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>Pages</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(name) FROM students";
            $rs1 = mysql_query($sql1,$con);
            $row1 = mysql_fetch_row($rs1);
            $total = $row1[0];
            $tp = ceil($total/10);

            for($i = 1; $i <= $tp; $i++)
            {
                echo "<a href='test.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
            }
        ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
                {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['ph_no']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </table>
        <?php
            $sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(name) FROM students";
            $rs1 = mysql_query($sql1,$con);
            $row1 = mysql_fetch_row($rs1);
            $total = $row1[0];
            $tp = ceil($total/10);

            for($i = 1; $i <= $tp; $i++)
            {
            echo "<a href='test.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I retrieve the table data without condition like in the code:

```
"SELECT * FROM students LIMIT ".$sf.",10";
```

it works, but when I add an condition like:

```
"SELECT * FROM `students` where `Instructor-Email`=". $_SESSION['ID'] ." OR `Instructor-Email` IS NULL LIMIT".$sf.",10"
```

it doesn't work.

I doubt my query syntax so I downloaded the query builder program (flyspeed sql query) and it built the query as:

```
"Select * From students Where (`Instructor-Email` = '. $_SESSION['ID'] .') Or (`Instructor-Email` Is Null) LIMIT 0,10"
```

but still didn't work!

Can you tell me what is the problem? With all my thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You should add backticks in the query around the field name Like this:

```
`Instructor-Email`=". $_SESSION['ID'] ." OR `Instructor-Email` IS NULL LIMIT".$sf.",10")
```

(If the field really exists and contains dash.)

Comment: thanks but if you mean ``, I did it before but didn't work :(

Comment: Do you have any error msg? Are you sure that this field is in this table? And not in for example instructors table?

Comment: yes I'm sure I used the same query in other page and it work correctly, I thought the error could be with the position of "LIMIT in the query, the message error come because the query didn't work correctly<I think> which is:  message error"Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\RecomA\test1.php on line 86

Answer (score 0):

From the  [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

Since your error states a passed boolean parameter on your `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, check your queries against the actual database with e.g. phpMyAdmin. Don't forget to check your `$sf` to contain a valid number on all cases.

> mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not
>   have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.

You can check with [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) if you even receive any results from your query.
But at first I would suggest you to check if you have all necessary rights on the table you want to query.

If you have only one database connection in your script, you don't need to pass the $con you assigned as a parameter to your further mysql function calls.

Please see the first answer by Lajos Veres and add always the backticks.

Comment: first of all thank you. but I said in my question that I know there is no retrieve occur from the query I put but the problem that I don't know why?! and about (``:backticks) I know I should use them when I have name like (a-b,a_b) but it didn't work  :(